# javafx - No maximize/minimize buttons on Stage with owner

Tags: java, javafx

When I set the owner of a `Stage` in my `JavaFX 14` application it disables the `minimize/maximize` controls on the window.

This code creates a new `Stage` with proper buttons, unless `s.initOwner` is called:

```
Stage s = new Stage();
s.setWidth(300);
s.setHeight(300);
// enabling this disables minimize/maximize buttons
// s.initOwner(parentStage);
s.setScene(new Scene(new Pane());
s.setResizable(true);
s.show();
```

Any ideas how to workaround it?

Comment: Right now in your browser, do File→Open.  Notice how that dialog does not have minimize/maximize buttons.  Windows owned by other windows are not supposed to be separately manageable.

Comment: Honestly, I just check and it truly does. All system dialogs (open, save, etc) do not have minimize buttons, but do have maximize buttons.
Moreover. as far as I read in the documentation, owned window share lifecycle with parent window; e.g. when parent is closed, owned window is closed too. Otherwise it would stick on the desktop. Noting is mentioned about maximize buttons.
Additionally, window is resizable. One can change size of it, so why not to maximize it?